# setTheme() not working when orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-orientation

I'm currently using setTheme() to dynamically set the theme for the Activity. Please note that I cannot use *android:configChanges="orientation* as I need the AlertDialog to recreate the layout for a landscape mode.

Whenever I use the setTheme() at initial point of the app, it works fine. However when I switch orientation, the theme reverts back to the original as set in the AndroidManifest. How do I go about this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Set your theme before calling super.onCreate(), e.g.

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme (...);
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    // go on with further initialization    
}
```

The behavior you've observed happens when super.onCreate() restores previous view and/or fragment states after orientation change, before your theme gets applied.

Comment: This answer fixed a bug I was having where rotating caused the splash screen graphic to overlay the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Set your theme dynamic in this method also.`public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}`

Comment: Hrmm..maybe I wasn't clear. The Activity and AlertDialog are two separate views. Whenever I use that setting, the AlertDialog doesn't reflow its layout to a landscape/potrait view. If I remove the setting, then the AlertDialog would be fine, but the Activity's Theme will be messed up